# Where does this picture come from (or what does it illustrate)?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Sorry if this doesn't belong here, but I do think this is math-related. I stumbled upon a interesting looking picture a while ago (I think it was either on Stackexchange or Reddit), and I had saved it to my desktop. I recall that it had some mathematical meaning to it (I think I remember a caption saying "this picture is the ... of roots of ...") or something.
Here is the picture:
[image: picture]

Comment: A reverse image search yields [this page](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~angell/index.html) with the caption *An exponential sum*.

Comment: Thanks. Strange. Reverse google image search was the first thing I tried; but it gave me nothing.  
I really think I saw it on Stackexchange some time within the last couple of months, and it had to do with some roots.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the explanation on [this page](https://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/about/exponential-sums). The author, David Angell says that this is the graph of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10620} e^{2 \pi i f(n)}$$
where
$$
f(n) = \frac{n}{dd}+\frac{n^2}{mm}+\frac{n^3}{yy}
$$
where $dd, mm, yy$ are the values corresponding to his date of birth. Partial sums are computed and consecutive complex values are joined by a straight line segment.